# Publish ASP.Net MVC Site (created in Visual Studio) to Azure using Azure Cmdlets

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I have a ASP.Net MVC Project in a solution which contains multiple other Class library projects (which are dependencies of MVC project).

Now I want to automate the process of creating multiple DEV AzureWebsites and publish the MVC project (along with its dependencies) through Azure PowerShell Cmdlets.

I know how to create AzureWebsite and other Cmdlets, but I am not sure about how to publish VS MVC Project, take that folder and deploy it in AzureWebsite. Please let me know my options.

PS - I do not want to Visual Studio -> Right Click publish option, because I need to create multiple instances of Dev AzureWebsites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news.  The script to do this is already written for you.  In Visual Studio, take a look in the **PublishScripts** folder of your solution. There you will find the scripts and parameter file for your solution. You can use these to publish to other Web Apps (formerly Websites).

The dependencies will be included in the package file that is generated so no additional steps are needed for that.

[image]